# regex and commas

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi this is working now but I am confused at to why.

I am learning regex and need to pull the numbers out of strings like

```
'Discount 7.5%' should get 7.5
'Discount 15%' should get 15
'Discount 10%' should get 10
'Discount 5%' should get 5
```

etc.

```
/\d,?.\d?/ //works

/\d,?.\d,?/ //doesn't works

/\d?.\d?/ //doesn't works
```

I thought one of the second two would work could someone explain this.

Comment: **1.** You should escape the dots `.` in all three regex by preceding it with \, **2.**  Use `\d+` to match more than one digits **3.** No need of `,` in any regex

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regular expression for DOT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862479/regular-expression-for-dot)

Comment: IMO, use [`(\d+(\.\d+)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/iL3dR1/1) with first capture group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty with easy to understand regex.

```
//Let the system to optimize the number parsing for efficiency
parseFloat(text.replace(/^\D+/, ""));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/4bnp8381/

Comment: Will replace `.` decimal too

Comment: @Tushar Nope It won't.

Comment: @Tushar True, but it's there just to make sure it only removes the non-digits in the front.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 , this would match `Fee 20%` too while it is not needed

Comment: I like this and you can add parseFloat(t.replace(/^Discount /, "")) if you want to have only Strings that start with Discount good way to get rid of the comma it even works with 'Discount 10% extra' and i thought that would break it https://jsfiddle.net/4bnp8381/2/

Comment: @ThomasK If you know `"Discount "` is always at the beginning of the string, you can even do `parseFloat("Discount 99% off".slice(9))` to completely get rid of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Make the second part with dot `.` optional with `?`

```
(\d)*(\.\d*)?
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you check this [**Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/oZ5pQ9/5), this is what you need so it will return the float number only if the word before it is **Discount** by making use of the *lookbehind* operator:

```
(?<=Discount\s)\d+(\.\d+)?
```

But the problem is that works with PHP(prce) I can't get it working with javascript.

**EDIT:**
As mentioned in here [regex and commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33536775/regex-and-commas/33537290#33537290) Javascript *does not* support lookbehind regex so here is what I did to work around it [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/forv02z1/)

```js
var div = document.getElementById('test');
var text = div.innerHTML;
div.innerHTML = text.replace(/Discount (.*)%/ig,'$1');
```

```html
<div id="test">
    Discount 7.5%<br>
    Discount 15%<br>
    discount 10%<br>
    Discount 5.433%<br>
    Fee 11%<br>
    Discount 22.7%
</div>
```

As you see it does match it only if it was followedd by the word **Discount**, the word `Fee 11%` does not match

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I'm sorry but it is not the same

Comment: My inputs are pretty standard but I do like that this checks for the word Discount. I tried starting using replace but in something like this i could not get it to work.      var re = /\d,?.\d?/;                          

            var vipextract = re.exec(cusvipdis);                   

            var skuextract = re.exec(skutext);

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following regex, which will match one or more digits, optionally followed by a decimal point and any number of digits:

```
^Discount\s(\d+(\.\d+)?)%$
```

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/dE8qE1/7)

Comment: @Tushar Thanks for catching this.  I did not test thoroughly enough.

Comment: `(\d+(\.\d+)?)` better?

Comment: @Tushar I would avoid the `+` operator since this is a percentage.  We don't want to allow for, say 4 digits in the beginning.

Comment: how about `\d+(\.\d+)?`

Comment: @Mi-Creativity It's the same, I just added brackets to get captured group

Comment: That what I wonder about, why do we need an outer group here?

Comment: @Mi-Creativity The other group is not used for capturing the result, it is just used for grouping two things `.` and `\d+`.